# sum with group by col not working properly - oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

i am trying to sum the qty and group by loc no , location,container name and qty but it is giving incorrect sum on the qty .. i have provided sample data that i created from table . any idea why sum with group by not working properly

```
select loc_no , location,container_name , sum(qty) as sum_qty
from table 
group by loc_no,location,container_name
```

sample data below

```
Loc no  location  container name  Qty
A       abc       12344           12
A       abc       2345            45
A       abc       22WER           56
A       abc       WWRR            34
B       xyz       WWRR            24
B       xyz       WWRR            45
B       xyz       12344           34
C       rmz       12344           65
C       rmz       12344           33
C       rmz       32WE            24
D       edc       32WE            34
D       ced       12344           54
```

Comment: *but it is giving incorrect sum on the qty* what is incorrect? Post the results that you get and your expected results.

Comment: do not post images of data or code, post the data or code itself

Comment: sure .. i will follow

Comment: in what way does the query you show not give the right results -- what results are you expecting

Answer (score 1):

If you want the sum for various grouping sets then you can use `CUBE`:

```sql
SELECT CASE GROUPING( loc_no ) WHEN 1 THEN 'ANY' ELSE loc_no END
         AS loc_no,
       CASE GROUPING( location ) WHEN 1 THEN 'ANY' ELSE location END
         AS location,
       CASE GROUPING( container_name ) WHEN 1 THEN 'ANY' ELSE container_name END
         AS container_name,
       SUM( Qty ) AS total_qty
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY CUBE( loc_no, location, container_name )
HAVING GROUPING( loc_no ) + GROUPING( location ) + GROUPING( container_name ) >= 2
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Loc_no, location, container_name, Qty ) AS
SELECT 'A', 'abc', '12344', 12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'abc', '2345',  45 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'abc', '22WER', 56 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'abc', 'WWRR',  34 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'xyz', 'WWRR',  24 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'xyz', 'WWRR',  45 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'xyz', '12344', 34 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'rmz', '12344', 65 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'rmz', '12344', 33 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'rmz', '32WE',  24 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', 'edc', '32WE',  34 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', 'ced', '12344', 54 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> LOC_NO | LOCATION | CONTAINER_NAME | TOTAL_QTY
> :----- | :------- | :------------- | --------:
> ANY    | ANY      | ANY            |       460
> ANY    | ANY      | 2345           |        45
> ANY    | ANY      | 32WE           |        58
> ANY    | ANY      | WWRR           |       103
> ANY    | ANY      | 12344          |       198
> ANY    | ANY      | 22WER          |        56
> ANY    | abc      | ANY            |       147
> ANY    | ced      | ANY            |        54
> ANY    | edc      | ANY            |        34
> ANY    | rmz      | ANY            |       122
> ANY    | xyz      | ANY            |       103
> A      | ANY      | ANY            |       147
> B      | ANY      | ANY            |       103
> C      | ANY      | ANY            |       122
> D      | ANY      | ANY            |        88
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a525fa8a4bcf99353e517ec690754f74)*